# Give an example of idempotent which is not projection.

Tags: functional-analysis

I m not getting example of idempotent which is not projection.plz help me out to get an answer.

Comment: A *linear* map $P$ with $P\circ P=P$, that's the definition of projection, isn't it?

Comment: To answer this question, one needs to know what definition of "idempotent" and what definition of "projection" you are working with. Please add this, and maybe more context.

Answer (score 1):

One way to define a projection is saying it is idempotent, so I assume you mean it is not a projection in a finite dimensional vector space. If that is what you want, then the following should work:

Let $H = (\Omega, A, P)$ be a probability space. Consider the operator that maps random variables to their expected value. That is, the operator $E$ that maps each real random variable $X$ defined on $H$ to the random variable Y, where 
$$
Y(\omega) = E(X) \, \forall \omega \in \Omega
$$

Then $E$ is idempotent.

As Torsten Schoeneberg said in the comments. For the above example to work, we need $\Omega$ to be large enough so that we are not looking at a finite dimensional vector space. So you can think of $\Omega$ as being the real numbers, per example.

Comment: Funny one, considering that "all random variables" do not even form a set, so this operator operates on ...?

Comment: Consider the RV defined on a certain probability space... will edit my answer

Comment: Well now if $\Omega$ is a finite set, this is actually a projection on a finite-dimensional vector space, but maybe I should stop nagging here.

Comment: Yeah right, if we want the example to be completly correct we should take care of those technicalities, but the ideia is there.